# Given that < and > are relations of N, what is > ∘ <?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I understood it correctly > ∘ < is (starting from right to left)

```
{ (x,y) : ∃z : { x < z && z > y } }
```

So the solution is

```
{ (x,y) : x and y are N }
```

Is that correct?

Comment: If z > x and z > y we don't know whether x > y or y > x. Sorry but I don't understand the rest of your question either.

Comment: @Suzu If the question is "Calculate > ∘ <" what would your answer be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given any $x,y \in \mathbb N$, the condition that $\exists z \in \mathbb N$ such that $x < z$ and $z > y$ is always satisfied. Indeed, we can just take $z = \max\{x, y\} + 1$.

Thus, it follows that:
$$
(>) \circ (<) = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \mid \exists z \in \mathbb N \text{ such that } x < z \text{ and } z > y\} = \mathbb N \times \mathbb N
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Just to make sure, that I understand it correctly, what would e.g. < ° < ° < be in this case? x < z and z < z and z < y = {}?

Comment: That would be:
$$
\{(a, d) \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \mid \exists b,c \in \mathbb N \text{ such that } a < b < c < d\}
=
\{(a, d) \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \mid d - a > 2\}
$$
For example, this set would contain $(2, 5)$ and $(3, 17)$ but not $(2, 4)$ or $(7, 3)$.

Comment: Thank you, I saw where my mistake was in that assumption.